# Blackberry error starting application: verification error

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jar, verification

I'm trying to use libraries in a project. The one i'm using is blackberry's Advanced UI sample library, which i added by creating a jar of it and preverifying it.
The code works fine, no issues.

However, I need to include **facebook** and **twitter** integration.
I'm trying to use facebook sdk 0.8.25 (requires `log4b.jar`) and twitter ME API 1.8.

I include them in the build path and tick for them to be copied at build.
When i run the application i get

> Error starting --- Module --- has verification error 2644 at offset 08e5

I've tried each jar separately, log4b give the same issue stating error 190.

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix my own fault with the help of this link 
http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/01/rim-blackberry-verification-errors.html

Basically the device is os6, and the build library was 7.1 which wasn't as issue before.
But it seems the imported libs were trying to use the 7.1 api.